# Solving: Poisson Distribution query

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, distributions

The distribution of a number of printing mistakes per page per book is Poisson with mean 3. Given that $e^{-3} = 0.047987$, the probability that there is some mistake is

a) 0.049787

b) 0.950212

c) 0.905020

d) None of the above.

The mean is given, as is the exponent value. It has been suggested that I take 1 - $e^{-3} $ but i did not understand why. That was the original doubt.

Comment: HINT: What is the probability that there is no mistake? The options should also serve as a hint themselves

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: "I don't know how to solve this" isn't sufficient for routine bookwork problems. You need to identify a *specific* roadblock. What can you do? What do you know about Poisson distributions? What union of elementary events is covered by "some mistake"?

Comment: @gung thanks for the tip- i'm new to stackexchange and that helped.

Comment: @Glen_b i agree it is routine but i have an exam tomorrow for admission to a master's course and i haven't revised basics for a while, plus i've been picking formulae off the net. sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: "routine bookwork" is another work for the material covered by out `self-study` tag. In order to follow the requirements for those questions (see gung's link), you must supply more information in your question.

Comment: This question appears to be ill-posed, because it does not specify the scope of "some mistake." Does it mean the chance there is some mistake in a particular page? If so, the answer will depend on how much of the page is typeset. The chance there is some mistake somewhere in the book? If so, it will depend on the number of pages in the book. Thus, *any* answer, to be fully supported, ought to explain how it is interpreting the question. The pedagogical value of this exercise consists not of the actual answer but in showing how assumptions lead to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of mistakes then $P(\text{atleast 1 mistake}) = 1 - P(\text{no mistake})$. What would be $X$ if there is no mistake? How will be the Poisson pdf with given mean of $3$?

Comment: oh right. i was wondering what the value of x would be in the poisson formula but here x is zero, so the denominator's 0!
thank you so much